# Python 2D numpy array from genfromtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data files with mixed string and numerical content. I.e.:

```
tag1 0.1 0.2 0.3
tag2 0.2 0.3 0.5
tag3 0.1 0.4 0.5
tag2 0.4 0.3 0.2
tag1 0.3 0.3 0.1
tag3 0.2 0.1 0.4
```

The ultimate goal is to extract an array to analyze (maybe plot) from column 2 and 3 for all elements where the tag is 'tag2'. (and other permutations thereof)

There was another discussion on stackoverflow indicating that reading the files would be best done by `genfromtxt` use `dtype=None` to understand the ascii entries.

Following that idea I tried;

```
x= np.genfromtxt('data1.rpt',dtype=None)
```

I expected a 2D array with 6 rows and 4 columns. But it turns out I got an array with 6 rows and some unexpected composite entries.

```
>>> x= np.genfromtxt('data1.rpt',dtype=None)
>>> x
array([('tag1', 0.1, 0.2, 0.3), ('tag2', 0.2, 0.3, 0.5),
       ('tag3', 0.1, 0.4, 0.5), ('tag2', 0.4, 0.3, 0.2),
       ('tag1', 0.3, 0.3, 0.1), ('tag3', 0.2, 0.1, 0.4)], 
      dtype=[('f0', 'S4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])
>>> x.shape
(6,)
>>>
```

What is the best way to process the files into an array which then can be filtered or sliced for content?

Your feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try pandas?

Comment: You have an array, so be specific about what you actually want. What do you mean filtered or sliced? Show an example result of the types of operations you have in mind

Comment: Access those fields by name  `x['f0']` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sticking with the data as loaded with `genfromtxt`:

```
In [155]: txt = b'''tag1 0.1 0.2 0.3
     ...: tag2 0.2 0.3 0.5
     ...: tag3 0.1 0.4 0.5
     ...: tag2 0.4 0.3 0.2
     ...: tag1 0.3 0.3 0.1
     ...: tag3 0.2 0.1 0.4'''.splitlines()
In [156]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype=None)
...
In [157]: data
Out[157]: 
array([(b'tag1', 0.1, 0.2, 0.3), (b'tag2', 0.2, 0.3, 0.5),
       (b'tag3', 0.1, 0.4, 0.5), (b'tag2', 0.4, 0.3, 0.2),
       (b'tag1', 0.3, 0.3, 0.1), (b'tag3', 0.2, 0.1, 0.4)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])
```

I'm in py3, so bytestrings display as `b'tag2'`'

This is a structured array, with fields instead of columns.

```
In [158]: data['f0']
Out[158]: array([b'tag1', b'tag2', b'tag3', b'tag2', b'tag1', b'tag3'], dtype='|S4')
```

So records with `tag2` are:

```
In [161]: mask = data['f0']==b'tag2'
In [162]: mask
Out[162]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False, False])
In [163]: data1=data[mask]
In [164]: data1
Out[164]: 
array([(b'tag2', 0.2, 0.3, 0.5), (b'tag2', 0.4, 0.3, 0.2)],
      dtype=[('f0', 'S4'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8')])
```

We can select the data columns from those records:

```
In [165]: col2 = data1['f1']
In [166]: col3 = data1['f2']
In [167]: col2
Out[167]: array([0.2, 0.4])
In [168]: col3
Out[168]: array([0.3, 0.3])
```

With `genfromtxt` I could have specified `usecols`.  With a 2 stage read we could skip the structured array.

Read once to get the tags:

```
In [170]: tags =np.genfromtxt(txt, usecols=[0], dtype=str)
In [171]: tags
Out[171]: array(['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag2', 'tag1', 'tag3'], dtype='<U4')
In [172]: mask = tags=='tag2'
In [173]: mask
Out[173]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False, False])
```

read again to get the data:

```
In [174]: data =np.genfromtxt(txt, usecols=[1,2,3])
In [175]: data
Out[175]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
       [0.2, 0.3, 0.5],
       [0.1, 0.4, 0.5],
       [0.4, 0.3, 0.2],
       [0.3, 0.3, 0.1],
       [0.2, 0.1, 0.4]])
In [176]: data[mask,:]
Out[176]: 
array([[0.2, 0.3, 0.5],
       [0.4, 0.3, 0.2]])
```

Or with a bit more cleaver use of `dtype`, I can load the data with 2 fields:

```
In [181]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt, dtype='U5,3f')
In [182]: data
Out[182]: 
array([('tag1', [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]), ('tag2', [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]),
       ('tag3', [0.1, 0.4, 0.5]), ('tag2', [0.4, 0.3, 0.2]),
       ('tag1', [0.3, 0.3, 0.1]), ('tag3', [0.2, 0.1, 0.4])],
      dtype=[('f0', '<U5'), ('f1', '<f4', (3,))])
In [183]: data['f0']
Out[183]: array(['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag2', 'tag1', 'tag3'], dtype='<U5')
In [184]: data['f1']
Out[184]: 
array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
       [0.2, 0.3, 0.5],
       [0.1, 0.4, 0.5],
       [0.4, 0.3, 0.2],
       [0.3, 0.3, 0.1],
       [0.2, 0.1, 0.4]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: I like the conversion approach. I would not know if the column slicing would have been as easy / intuitive in the structured array. I gave this the up-arrow.

Answer (score 0):

With pandas, you could use [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). The types are recognized automatically:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data1.rpt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
>>> df
      0    1    2    3
0  tag1  0.1  0.2  0.3
1  tag2  0.2  0.3  0.5
2  tag3  0.1  0.4  0.5
3  tag2  0.4  0.3  0.2
4  tag1  0.3  0.3  0.1
5  tag3  0.2  0.1  0.4
>>> df[df[0] == 'tag2'][[0, 1, 2]]
      0    1    2
1  tag2  0.2  0.3
3  tag2  0.4  0.3
```

Comment: A friendly remark: column 0 is an index: `df=df.set_index(0); df.loc['tag2']`.

Comment: @DYZ: Thanks. I wasn't sure that it should be used as an index since it doesn't have unique values.

Comment: I like the idea. Will this approach be good to go forward when the next step is using numpy/scipy interp1d? Let's say we now have multiple 'tag2' entries and the second and third columns are x / f(x) values that are to be used as points for a interpolation function f_i(x) for other x values not in the data files?

Comment: @DYZ: Indeed, but I guess only OP can tell if the tag column should be the index.

Comment: @GertGottschalk: pandas is basically a mix of numpy and python dicts. You can do whatever you'd like on the columns, which are numpy arrays.

Comment: @Eric Duminil: Yes, the tag column could be seen as an index. As indicated the plan is to get all data from an index (which should be a 2D array) and then do some analysis on rows/columns. Then compare to other indices.